# Removing Login as portal user option

Tags: community, customer-portal

In the manage external user button options, i want to remove login as a portal option as i am currently having communities.
When i click on login as a portal user it shows No available portal. so this option is of no use for me.
I checked and found that it has been posted as an idea few months back [Idea1](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ktUiAAI) and [Idea2](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqgGAAS).
Is any solution available yet?[image]

Answer (score -3):

check out this idea:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ktUiAAI
Looks like this is not possible

Comment: User already stated in the question that they checked that link